# Unable to find Alexa-skill-kit-sdk-factskill blueprint on aws lamda

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm quite a beginner to Alexa skill set. Trying to add a node.js skill to Alexa following few nuggets from the internet. I have created skill on amazon developer console and trying to create aws lambda function on aws console. Surprisingly, when I tried creating a lambda function, I could not find any blueprint matching to "Alexa" keyword.

Here are the steps -:
    1.Got to aws.amazon.com and log in
    2. Search for the Lambda service and go to it
    3. Click on Create a function
    4. Click on Blueprints
    5. Search for “Alexa”

I did some research and it says, changing to North. Virginia region could help but no luck so far.

Any such leads would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

if you are unable to find "alexa-skills-kit-nodejs-factskill" under the section "Use a blueprint",
please look for it under the section "Browse serverless app repository",it doesnt matters whatever the location you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use cloudformation application templates instead. Though they are still outdated (like the blueprints out there). My advice is that you create an [Alexa Hosted Skill](http://alexa.design/hosted) instead